# Selenium Xpath to get Phone Number from Kijiji

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to extract the number from number field in Kijiji, When I write the Xpath in console it identifying and highlighting the filed too but when I run the code I am getting NoSuchElementException exception.

Here is the screenshot of DOM

[image]

And Here is the Screenshot of the code and Error

[image]

Screenshots of Xpath which I have tried

[image]
[image]

Here is the URL

```
https://www.kijiji.ca/b-cars-trucks/edmonton/c174l1700203?adRemoved=4722799
```

And here is the complete code which I wrote

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome("E:\\Selenium\Driver\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.kijiji.ca/b-cars-trucks/edmonton/c174l1700203?adRemoved=4722799")

vehicleTitles = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//a[contains(@class,'title')]")

for title in vehicleTitles:

    print(title.text)
    driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,title.text).click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[contains(@class,'phoneNumberContainer')]").click()


    Number = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[contains(@class,'phoneNumberContainer')]")
    print(Number.text)
    driver.maximize_window()
```

Comment: Please post your code and url, So it's easier to reproduce.

Comment: URL and complete code addedd

Comment: I think it might be due to the page redirection failure, So put more loggings`d = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,title.text); print(d); d.click()`

Comment: The aim of program is to scrap Vehicle Name and Phone Number. 

The Vehicle name is showing on the front page but for the phone we have to next page after clicking the vehicle name and on the next page we can get the number. 

Now, My program is getting the vehicle and clicking and going to next page too but i can't able to get the number field from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

Some of them don't have the phone number, so I updated them as 'No Phone Number Available'.

```
# add the below import statement
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

# use the below driver instantiation statement instead of yours.
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service("E:\\Selenium\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe"))



all_titles = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class,'title')]")
    for i in range(len(all_titles)):
        print("Title: ", all_titles[i].text)
        all_titles[i].click()
        sleep(3)
        try:
            phone_no_container = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with(@class,'phoneNumberContainer-')]")
            root_container = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".root-2377010271.light-3420168793.container-3656255093")
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", root_container)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print("No Phone Number Available")
        else:
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'Reveal')]").click()
            sleep(1)
            print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with(@class,'phoneShowNumberButton-')]/span").text)
        driver.back()
        sleep(3)
        all_titles = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class,'title')]")
        print("-----")
```

Comment: I used your code but the program crashed on 12th line. 

Here is the attached screenshot :

[![Screenshot-4.png](https://i.postimg.cc/bwQFDJZk/Screenshot-4.png)](https://postimg.cc/LJ8VGmB8)

Comment: It is a different error, 'executable_path' has been deprecated.  Added the driver instantiation statement in the above code, you have to use 'Service' object.